# Super weird glitch when remeshing 2 joined curves

Tags: bezier-curves, sculpting, remesh, curve-modifier

I have 2 curves that I turned into a mesh and joined. I then go to sculpt the curves but first remesh the object, and a very weird glitch occurs with one of the curves where It completely becomes carved out.

[image][image][image]

what is happening and how do I fix this?